# MySQL not starting, systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe"

Tags: mysql

System:Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
MYSQL: 5.7.31

Tried following commands all shows the same error

systemctl start mysql

/etc/init.d/mysql start

service mysql start

journalctl -xe shows following

```
Sep 19 05:38:32 www systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server... 
Sep 19 05:38:32 www mysql-systemd-start[2938]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
**Sep 19 05:38:32 www mysql-systemd-start[2938]: /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start: line 44: mysqld: command not found** 
Sep 19 05:38:32 www mysql-systemd-start[2938]: Please take a look at  https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues. 
Sep 19 05:38:32 www mysql-systemd-start[2938]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service. 
Sep 19 05:38:32 www systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1 Sep 19 05:38:32 www systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
Sep 19 05:38:32 www systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server. Sep 19 05:38:32 www systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart. 
Sep 19 05:38:32 www systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1. 
Sep 19 05:38:32 www systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

I've highlighted the line that I think is creating a problem

$PATH is
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

/usrs/bin content related to mysql

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4027496 Jul 20 10:50 myisamchk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3916200 Jul 20 10:50 myisam_ftdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3894296 Jul 20 10:50 myisamlog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3945448 Jul 20 10:50 myisampack
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3608840 Jul 20 10:50 my_print_defaults
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3908456 Jul 20 10:50 mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3799752 Jul 20 10:50 mysqladmin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       10 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlanalyze -> mysqlcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4068280 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlbinlog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3825320 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     5350 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3627200 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_config_editor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    26952 Jul 20 10:50 mysqld_multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    27790 Jul 20 10:50 mysqld_safe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3875176 Jul 20 10:50 mysqldump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     7865 Jul 20 10:50 mysqldumpslow
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22627736 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_embedded
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3791912 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlimport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5224224 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_install_db
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       10 Jul 20 10:50 mysqloptimize -> mysqlcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3616952 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_plugin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4286152 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlpump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       10 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlrepair -> mysqlcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    39016 Jan 12  2018 mysqlreport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3788520 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_secure_installation
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3790504 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlshow
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3809512 Jul 20 10:50 mysqlslap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3653288 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_ssl_rsa_setup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3569976 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4446416 Jul 20 10:50 mysql_upgrade
```

Any idea what's wrong? What to do?

Comment: Try to force reinstall the mysql-server package. Obviously `/usr/sbin/mysqld` is missing

Comment: very hard to guess what could be wrong. Describe your scenario what went wrong. what were you doing that caused it to happen? did you install something ?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all the mysql packages with apt-get remove one by one and then reinstalled them again. I did not delete /var/lib/mysql directory where all data were there. After re-installation everything worked fine and data are also safe. All tables and sites working. I am not sure but i think last package upgrade caused this.